Poker bets on Python
I'm writing poker for my bot in discord.  So far I'm presenting an incomplete version of the project, which is only a betting system. The development took a lot of time, so I decided to ask for help.  Perhaps something in the project structure could be optimized.
import sys, os; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ''))

import poker 
import random

from icecream import ic
from inputimeout import inputimeout, TimeoutOccurred
import itertools
from _functions_base import *

import time
import threading
import asyncio
import os

TIME_FOR_TURN = 300

def check_for_int(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


class Players:
    players = []
    class Player:
        def __init__(self, name, stack):
            self.name = name
            
            Players.players.append(self)
            self.id = len(Players.players)
            
            self.stack = stack
            self.hand = []
            
            self.current_bet = 0
            self.money_in_pot = 0
            
            self.in_game = True
            self.all_in = False
            self.all_in_amount = 0
            self.fold = False
            
            self.winner = False
        
        def __repr__(self):
            return self.name
        
        def bet(self, amount):
            self.stack -= amount
            if self.stack > 0:
                self.current_bet += amount
            else:
                self.all_in = True
                self.all_in_amount = amount + self.stack
                self.current_bet += amount + self.stack
        
        def wait_for_action(self, table):
            def ask():
                try:
                    answer = inputimeout(f"{self.name}, enter an action:\n", timeout=TIME_FOR_TURN)
                    if answer == "fold":
                        self.fold = True
                    elif answer == "call":
                        self.bet(table.last_bet - self.current_bet)
                    elif "raise" in answer:
                        amount_to_call = table.last_bet - self.current_bet
                        try: 
                            answer = int(answer.split(" ")[1])
                        except:
                            ask()
                        if answer < 0:
                            ask()
                            
                        if answer <= amount_to_call:
                            ask()
                        else:
                            table.was_raised = True
                            table.last_bet = self.current_bet + answer
                            self.bet(answer)
                        
                except TimeoutOccurred:
                    if table.last_bet != 0:
                        self.fold = True
            ask()
        
class Table:
    def __init__(self, big_blind):
        self.members = []
        self.players = []
        self.street = 0
        self.community_cards = []
        
        self.pot = 0
        
        self.small_blind = big_blind/2
        self.big_blind = big_blind
        
        self.dealer_id = 0
        self.current_player = 0
        
        self.was_raised = False
        self.last_bet = 0
        
class Game:
    def __init__(self, big_blind):
        self.table = Table(big_blind)
        
        self.deck = list(poker.Card)
        random.shuffle(self.deck)
        
        self.deck_index = 0
        
        self.game_over = False
        
        self.dealer = None
        self.winner = None
        
        self.round_over = False
        self.round_winner = None
        
        self.round_winners = []
        
        self.round_winner_hand = None
        
        self.round_winner_hand_name = None
        
    def determine_winner(self):
        print("Game over")
        
    def deal_cards(self):
        for player in self.table.players:
            player.hand = [self.deck.pop(), self.deck.pop()]
            
    def player_placement(self):
        self.table.players.remove(self.dealer)
        self.table.players.append(self.dealer)
        
    def start_new_game(self):
        self.table.members = self.table.players
        self.deal_cards()
        self.dealer = random.choice(self.table.players)
        self.player_placement()
    
    def next_game(self):
        self.table.players = self.table.members
        self.deal_cards()
        self.dealer = self.table.players[0]
        self.player_placement()
    
    def turn(self):
        # Итерация по игрокам и ожидание их действий
        for player in self.table.players:
            player.wait_for_action(self.table)

        # Удаление игроков, которые сбросили карты
        #self.table.players = [player for player in self.table.players if not player.fold]

        if len(self.table.players) == 1:
            self.round_over = True
            return self.determine_winner()
        
        # Проверка, сравняли ли все ставки
        all_bets_equal = all(player.current_bet == self.table.last_bet for player in self.table.players)

        # Если не все ставки сравнялись, продолжаем раунд
        i = 0
        while not all_bets_equal:
            # Итерация по игрокам и дополнительное ожидание их действий
            if i != 0:
                all_bets_equal = all(player.current_bet == self.table.last_bet for player in self.table.players)
            for player in self.table.players:
                if all_bets_equal:
                    break
                if not player.fold:
                    if player.all_in:
                        continue
                    if self.table.was_raised and player.current_bet == self.table.last_bet:
                        break
                    else:
                        player.wait_for_action(self.table)
            i += 1
            # Обновление списка игроков после возможных дополнительных ставок или фолдов
            self.table.players = [player for player in self.table.players if not player.fold]

            # Проверка, сравняли ли все ставки после всех возможных действий
            all_bets_equal = all(player.current_bet == self.table.last_bet for player in self.table.players)

            # Если все ставки равны, выходим из цикла
            if all_bets_equal:
                break

        # Увеличение улицы (street) и переход к следующему раунду
        self.table.street += 1
        self.table.last_bet = 0
        self.table.was_raised = False
        for player in self.table.players:
            self.table.pot += player.current_bet
            player.money_in_pot += player.current_bet 
            player.current_bet = 0
        
        Game.next_round(self)
                
            
    def next_round(self):
        self.table.street
        if self.table.street == 0:
            Game.turn(self)
            
        if self.table.street == 1:
            flop = [self.deck.pop(), self.deck.pop(), self.deck.pop()]
            self.table.community_cards.extend(flop)
            print(*self.table.community_cards)
            Game.turn(self)
            
        if self.table.street == 2:
            turn = self.deck.pop()
            self.table.community_cards.append(turn)
            print(*self.table.community_cards)
            Game.turn(self)
            
        if self.table.street == 3:
            river = self.deck.pop()
            self.table.community_cards.append(river)
            print(*self.table.community_cards)
            Game.turn(self)
            
        if self.table.street == 4 and not self.round_over:
            self.round_over = True
            self.determine_winner()
        


def test_players():
    player1 = Players.Player("Player1", 1000)
    player2 = Players.Player("Player2", 1000)
    player3 = Players.Player("Player3", 1000)
    player4 = Players.Player("Player4", 1000)
    
    game = Game(100)
    game.table.players.append(player1)
    game.table.players.append(player2)
    game.table.players.append(player3)
    game.table.players.append(player4)
    game.start_new_game()
    game.next_round()
    print(game.round_winners)
test_players()


Are you able to include English translations of your code's comments?  That would help reviewers here, as we're an English-language site.

sys.path
import sys, os; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ''))

No, please don't do that.
Prefer to have bash set the PYTHONPATH env var properly
before we even start the interpreter.
You might use a brief shell script or Makefile recipe
to accomplish that, so caller has cd'd to
the right place before invoking this program.
You might even fix it with a shebang:
#! /usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/mypkg:. python3

Also, Pep-8
asked you nicely to put import os on its own line.
Just run "$ isort *.py"
to fix things up.
automagic
Please don't do this:
from _functions_base import *

I imagine you wrote that module.
I have no idea what symbols you just imported,
potentially overriding existing builtins.
So now the rest of your code will be a mystery,
because when I read some_identifier I won't
know which module that identifier came from,
nor what its implementation does.
It's seldom a good idea to start a module name with _ underscore.
Also, when you name a module, please give it a proper name
instead of a throwaway name.
Yes, I know that the definition of "functions" will be within the module.
Tell me something about what they do, give me a hint, don't obfuscate.
BTW, here is an excellent identifier, which clearly uses
SI
units of seconds:
TIME_FOR_TURN = 300

conventional names
This is an OK name:
def check_for_int(value):

There's no docstring, but it only takes a moment to read
the very clear code.
That quickly reveals we have a predicate with no side effects.
If you had named it def is_int then the Gentle Reader
wouldn't even have to peruse the body of the code,
as the conventional is_ prefix tells us all that we need.
nested classes
class Players:
    players = []
    class Player:

Prefer to put Player up at the top module-level.
Consider deleting the Players class, as it doesn't
seem to do much. It looks like a function or perhaps a Game
should have responsibility for tracking current players.
In particular, this seems Bad:
            Players.players.append(self)

If each Player needs a distinct ID for some reason,
you might pass it into the __init__ ctor.
I do thank you for introducing all object attributes
up front in the ctor.
repr()
        def __repr__(self):
            return self.name

This is OK, keep it as-is if you like it.
But consider making this __str__ instead of __repr__.
Alternatively, consider returning a longer formatted string
which would be a valid invocation of __init__.
Here is a familiar example:
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> 
>>> @dataclass
... class Point:
...     x: float
...     y: float
... 
>>> p = Point(3, 4)
>>>
>>> repr(p)
'Point(x=3, y=4)'

type annotations
Well, now, here's a surprise!
        def __init__(self, name, stack):
            ...            
            self.stack = stack
            ...
        
        def bet(self, amount):
            self.stack -= amount

I thought for sure we were passing in a list, not a float,
since people often use that to implement a
stack
datastructure.
And then I read the decrement, which changed my mind.
Apparently we're talking about a "stack of currency"
instead of using more standard banker's terms.
Also, weirdly, our stack of bills upon the table
can have negative height?!?
That's just not very intuitive.
Please, please offer a hint in the signature about what's going on:
        def __init__(self, name: str, stack: float) -> None:

It's good for the Gentle Reader, and
it helps mypy to help you.
look before you leap
This "undo" logic is needlessly confusing:
                self.all_in_amount = amount + self.stack
                self.current_bet += amount + self.stack

We do an overdraw "whoops!", and then pretend it never happened.
Prefer to check for adequate funds prior to the decrement,
similar to how human bankers operate,
so there's no need for a fixup.
You may find the min() function convenient
when deciding how big a bet our current funds can support.
bare except
                        except:
                            ask()

No, please don't do that.
Prefer except Exception:,
so we don't disable important items like CTRL/C handling.
Always lint prior to submitting code for review.
Had you run ruff check *.py
on this source code, it would have reported
E722 Do not use bare `except`

Also, you want a while loop.
Re-invoking ask() from within ask() can lead to a stack overflow.
int vs. float
        self.small_blind = big_blind / 2

It's possible that you intended // 2 there, to obtain an integer result.
callable
        self.deck = list(poker.Card)

Maybe you intended to create a card object?
        self.deck = list(poker.Card())

Also, we see some self.round_over interaction,
and this method makes a
promise
which it does not fulfill:
    def determine_winner(self):
        print("Game over")

docstring
        # Итерация по игрокам и ожидание их действий

Please make that a turn() """docstring""", rather than a # comment.
Also, consider revisiting your choice of language,
at least for code to be submitted to an Anglophone site like Code Review.
The English-language identifiers are all very nice.
You found it necessary to write lots of comments.
Maybe turn() is getting too big, and deserves Extract Helper
in order to shrink it, pushing out some of its complexity.
main guard
Please use the standard idiom:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_players()

Consider turning this into a proper
test suite
which "knows the right answer",
so it can display Green bar
without you having to manually eyeball it
and evaluate whether the output is correct or not.
Consider putting tests in a separate module which imports this one.

You are calling ask() from within def ask():. This can lead to a stack overflow if it is repeated often enough, like when the amount_to_call is repeatedly too low. (The interpreter might prevent it due to tail call optimization, but I wouldn't bet on it.)
A better solution might be to use a loop instead of recursion. Something like this pseudo-code:
while True:
    answer = read user input
    if answer is valid:
        handle answer
        break


Although English is not my native language, I write all comments in English, and I would recommend you do the same, for 2 main reasons: First of all, it makes it easier to share the code with others, even if just to ask for help. Secondly, most programming languages, including Python, rely heavily on the English language for keywords, standard library identifiers, and documentation.

self.small_blind = big_blind/2 could lead to non-integer small blinds, which may or may not be acceptable in your case. According to Wikipedia, the small blind is typically rounded down to the next whole number (integer).

It seems like determine_winner doesn't actually determine the winner. It just prints "Game over". A more fitting name might be announce_winner, but even then I would expect it to at least mention the winner's name. Currently, the most descriptive name seems to be announce_end_of_game.

Unless I'm missing something, the first line in the method next_round (self.table.street) does nothing useful.

It wasn't quite clear to me at first glance what i is. If it actually just counts the number of iterations of the while loop to avoid the all_bets_equal = all(...) call in the first iteration, then I'm not sure why that is necessary. You are calling it right before the loop anyway and it seems like it has no side effects, so calling it twice shouldn't be a problem and would make the logic easier to understand.
You could further simplify that logic by extracting the all_bets_equal = all(...) into a method or function and calling it whenever all_bets_equal is used.
